# Akka Actor Passing Actor References Around

Tags: akka

I have two Actor instances like below:

```
class MyActor1(actorRef2: Actor) extends Actor {
  ....
  ....
}

class MyActor2 extends Actor {
  ....
  ....
}
```

Both the above actors are created from a top level actor where I have some supervison.

Now my question is if MyActor2 is somehow killed, what happens to the reference of this MyActor2 that I passed in to MyActor1? Will MyActor1 still can send messages using the reference passed in to it so that MyActor2 after resurrection still gets the messages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What happens depends on what you mean by "killed" and what the supervisor strategy for `MyActor2` is.

1. If the reference to `MyActor2` is stopped via the [`stop`](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/actors.html#stopping-actors) method, such as `context.stop(myActor2)`, then:

   > Processing of the current message, if any, will continue before the actor is stopped, but additional messages in the mailbox will not be processed. By default these messages are sent to the deadLetters of the ActorSystem, but that depends on the mailbox implementation.
2. If the reference to `MyActor2` is stopped with a [`PoisonPill`](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/actors.html#poisonpill) message, then:

   > ...the `akka.actor.PoisonPill` message...will stop the actor when the message is processed. `PoisonPill` is enqueued as ordinary messages and will be handled after messages that were already queued in the mailbox.
3. If the reference to `MyActor2` is stopped with a [`Kill`](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/actors.html#killing-an-actor) message, then:

   > Unlike `PoisonPill` this will cause the actor to throw a[n] `ActorKilledException`, triggering a failure. The actor will suspend operation and its supervisor will be asked how to handle the failure, which may mean resuming the actor, restarting it or terminating it completely.

If you stop `myActor2` with `context.stop` or `PoisonPill`, then messages that are sent to that actor after it has stopped will go to dead letters. If you send `myActor2` a `Kill` message, then whatever supervisor strategy you have defined for handling an `ActorKilledException` will kick in. The [default supervisor strategy](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/fault-tolerance.html#default-supervisor-strategy) for handling an `ActorKilledException` is to stop the actor, which, as mentioned, will cause all messages sent after the actor has stopped to enter the dead letter mailbox.

You can override this default behavior by changing the supervisor strategy to restart the actor in the event of an `ActorKilledException`. Restarts preserve the `ActorRef` and are transparent to entities that have a reference to the actor: messages sent to the actor while it is restarting and afterwards will be processed normally. You could also resume the actor, which basically ignores the exception.

Comment: Ok so that means there is a guarantee that once I restart the MyActor2, I can still continue processing new messages that are sent from MyActor1! This is what I want!

Comment: A key point being “restart (using supervision)”. If you’d stop the actor, and happen to start a new on with the same name, the previous actor ref would be invalid. The red remains valid if you use the restart supervision though